# Saving complete azure configuration to file?

Tags: azure, azure-configuration

Is there any way to save the complete state of my azure configuration?

Basically, I just created a demo for a project I'm working on. This demo has a website/webjob, scheduler, storage queue, storage blob, redis cache and documentDB. I have configured these components in terms of size/scale/schedules but now the demo is done.

I don't want to pay for these services and I don't need them online for now. However, I don't want to have to recreate and reconfigure them if I need to relaunch the demo in a month. 
Is there a way to save my current azure configurations to a file and then to be able to recreate all the services again automatically (with a script or a small program)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good question, that sums up a historical problem we're in the process of making easier and more flexible. I'll answer this question with two parts.

First and foremost, you have tools like the PowerShell cmdlets now, that you can script out the creation of an entire "world" in Azure and then re-run whenever you want, against a subscription, to scaffold out a whole architecture. You can also use the management libraries for .NET to do this from a .NET application. When we embarked on the VS WebJobs tooling, for instance, I worked up a prototype for my developers on using MAML to create WebJobs and scheduler job collections. You can see the demo code for that here: https://github.com/bradygaster/maml-demo-scheduled-webjob-creator

We've also recently embarked on new mission of re-creating a lot of the management APIs so that they support the notion of templates and resource groups, to marry up with the new portal experience. Here's a great MSDN article that discusses how the PowerShell cmdlets for the Gallery could be used to pull down a list of the various templates that could then be pushed back up as fully-baked architectures running in Azure. You have the capability of building these templates yourself, then you could use these cmdlets to fan out and create things that you write up in your own custom templates. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn654596.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Both of these only work when the site is originally created using the solution.  Neither of these will work for a site that has already been created and configured, for example, through the portal.

Comment: yes, this doesn't actually seem very helpful because after you've configured it the way you want... you need to do it again using shell/API...

Answer (score 0):

For Azure websites you can use the Back and Restore option to store the site and restore it back when you want to demo again, But all you have to do is Stop the services and you should be able to keep the demo without incurring cost.